# re enabling ng-disabled button in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am a newbie to AngularJS. I have created a form with fields which is disabled using `ng-disabled` by default. when I click on the edit `<button>` I want these fields to re-enable.

HTML

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="edit_setting()" ng-controller="ExchangeController">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.name" ng-disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Host Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.host_name" required ng-disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.address" ng-disabled="true">
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Controller

```
  function ExchangeController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
    var edit_exchange_setting = "https://pvbp.com/api/settings.html?contactid=292351&exchange_id=7124&clearinghouseid=1&token=e5349652507c0esae86d50fdbdc53222cf97&page=view";
      $http.get(edit_exchange_setting).success(function(response){
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_name = response.name;
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_host_name = response.host_name;
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_last_processed_date = response.address;   
      });

      $scope.edit_exchange_setting_click = (function(){
      // how can i make the fields re enable here

      });
  }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in controller create scope variable,

```
$scope.disabled= true;
```

and replace all `ng-disabled` with that variable like,

```
...ng-model="exchange_dt.name" ng-disabled="disabled"....
```

when you click on edit button set `$scope.disabled` to `false` like,

```
$scope.edit_exchange_setting_click = (function(){      
    $scope.disabled = false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you can have a scope variable keeping the `true` or `false` value.and a setter for that variable.

```
  function ExchangeController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
var edit_exchange_setting = "https://pvbp.com/api/settings.html?contactid=292351&exchange_id=7124&clearinghouseid=1&token=e5349652507c0esae86d50fdbdc53222cf97&page=view";
  $http.get(edit_exchange_setting).success(function(response){
    $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_name = response.name;
    $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_host_name = response.host_name;
    $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_last_processed_date = response.address;   
  });

  $scope.edit_exchange_setting_click = (function(){
  // how can i make the fields re enable here

  });

  $scope.dtName=true;
   $scope.isdtNameDisabled=function()
    {
      return $scope.dtName;
    };
  $scope.updatedtName=function(flag)
  {
  $scope.dtName=flag;
};
```

}

and in your HTML you can bind that getter function.

```
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.name" ng-disabled="isdtNameDisabled()>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a variable at the top of controller say

```
$scope.mydisabled=true;
```

then set your ng-disable with the variable

ng-disabled="mydisabled"

and on click of edit button set its value to false

```
$scope.mydisabled=false;
```

**UPDATE**
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nkv7n4ng/)

Answer (score 1):

A different (however similar) approach is to wrap your form contents in a fieldset and have ng-disabled in the fieldset only rather than in all the input fields. To make the html more cleaner.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="edit_setting()" ng-controller="ExchangeController">
  <fieldset ng-disabled ="isFormSetForSaving">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Host Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.host_name" required>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="exchange_dt.address">
      </div>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
  </form>
```

and now in the controller set the isFormSetForSaving to true/false as per your logic.

```
function ExchangeController($scope, $http, $cookieStore, $location) {
    $scope.isFormSetForSaving = true;
    var edit_exchange_setting = "https://pvbp.com/api/settings.html?contactid=292351&exchange_id=7124&clearinghouseid=1&token=e5349652507c0esae86d50fdbdc53222cf97&page=view";
      $http.get(edit_exchange_setting).success(function(response){
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_name = response.name;
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_host_name = response.host_name;
        $scope.exchange_dt.exchange_last_processed_date = response.address;   
      });

      $scope.edit_exchange_setting_click = (function(){
      // how can i make the fields re enable here
          $scope.isFormSetForSaving = false;
      });
  }
```